# Dedicated server running VPS how should I back it up?

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, vps, dedicated-server

We are renting a dedicated server and running a vps within it. We would like to back up the vps so if there is an issue we can restore quickly either from another server or from the current server.

The size of the vps uncompressed approx 50gb at this point.

Would a 2nd hard drive be sufficient or should we be looking to back it up some other way? What suggestions do you guys have to back up ~50gb a night?

When we do, what is the best way to compress it and copy it so save space and bandwidth?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

=== UPDATED ===

To clarify the questions below:

1. Operating System:  Both the hosting os and the vm is Windows 2008 Server
2. We are using VMWARE to run the vps
3. The dedicated server is a rented server that we do not have access to. The vps is ours, which is actually the current server imaged and modified.
4. We can have a 2nd drive put in but I'm not sure how to copy a vm while it is in use.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your system likely has 3 components:

- the supplied operating system and supporting siftware (such as webserver, DBMS etc) - essentially all the 'packaged' softwaer
- your application code
- your application data
- log data

While there are dependencies in here, each of these components has a different change frequency. Backing them all up in one is nice and simple - but is obviously causing you some problems. What's the relative size of each? Usually the data is the largest part - can you do incremental backups of this?

Simply grabbing 50Gb of data from a running system may cause an interruption to the service - how do you ensure that your backup image is consistent?

Do you own the hardware the system is running on? More specifically, do you just own the VPS? If so, have you spoken to the service provider to see if they can provide local storage for the image which you can the rsync from?

Which also begs the question, what OS are you using? (and what is the DBMS and dev language?)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Backup and Replication Tool by Veeam Software or Trilead VM Explorer to backup your VPS servers.. Both of them are great VMware backup options!

Source: [Importance of Windows VPS Backup Solution](http://www.vpswebserver.com/windows-vps/importance-of-windows-vps-backup-solutions)s